# What is a better way to switch between Grid and Linear of RecyclerView with MVVM?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView and a FAB in a Fragment.
The FAB switches the layout of the RecyclerView between GRID and LINEAR.

I have a enum class in the ViewModel.

```
enum class LAYOUT { GRID, LINEAR }

private val _layout = MutableLiveData<LAYOUT>()
val layout: LiveData<LAYOUT>
     get() = _layout
```

And the fragment observes the MutableLiveData of the layout value in ViewModel.

I now kind of get it working by having 2 ListAdapter, one for Grid and one for Linear.
Below is my code of the Fragment.

```
        val gridAdapter = MovieGridAdapter()

        viewModel.layout.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            if (it == GRID) {
                binding.recyclerViewMovie.adapter = gridAdapter
                binding.recyclerViewMovie.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 3)
            } else {
                binding.recyclerViewMovie.adapter = linearAdapter
                binding.recyclerViewMovie.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
            }
        })

        viewModel.trendingMovies.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            it?.let {
                gridAdapter.submitList(it)
                linearAdapter.submitList(it)
            }
        })
```

I feel like this is not the best way to do it, as I now have 2 adapters in the fragment, and I need to submitList for both adapters.

Please let me know if there is a better way to do this, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use two adapters one adapter can do the work

```
class ProductListAdapter(
private val listener: OnProductListener) : PagedListAdapter<Product, ProductViewHolder>( PRODUCT_COMPARATOR ) {

var layoutId: Int = R.layout.list_item_product

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ProductViewHolder, position: Int) {

    val product = getItem(position)

    with(holder) {
        bindTo(product,true)
        product.let { product ->
            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                product.product_id?.let { it1 -> listener.onProductSelected(it1) }
            }
        }
    }
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ProductViewHolder {
    val view =
        LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(layoutId, parent, false)

    return ProductViewHolder(view)
}

override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    return position
}

fun setLayoutResourceId(layoutId: Int) {
    this.layoutId = layoutId
}


companion object {

    private val PRODUCT_COMPARATOR = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Product>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Product, newItem: Product): Boolean =
            TextUtils.equals(
                oldItem.product_id,
                newItem.product_id
            ) 

        override fun areContentsTheSame(
            oldItem: Product,
            newItem: Product
        ): Boolean =
            oldItem == newItem

    }

 }

}
```

---

in you fragment define the adapter

```
private var productsAdapter: ProductListAdapter = ProductListAdapter(this)

viewModel.trendingMovies.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        it?.let {
            productsAdapter.submitList(it)

        }
    })
```

---

**showList**

```
  private fun showList() {
    rv_products.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)
    productsAdapter.setLayoutResourceId(R.layout.list_item_list_product)
    rv_products.adapter = productsAdapter

}
```

---

**showGrid**

```
private fun showGrid() {
    rv_products.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(activity, 3)
    productsAdapter.setLayoutResourceId(R.layout.list_item_grid_product)
    rv_products.adapter = productsAdapter
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The reason of having 2 adapters is that I have different layout for GRID and LINEAR.

Comment: do you mean different xml `layout` for gird item and list item? if though then `setLayoutResourceId` will handle this

Comment: Thanks for answer again and I figured out! I pass a parameter to the adapter and it inflates Grid or Linear xml layout.